# How to use django-admin.py with GAE installed on OSX?

Tags: python, django, macos, google-app-engine, django-1.5

I can not understand how to create .po and .mo files to use [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/) in my GAE project. I found django-admin.py at `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/bin/django-admin.py`, but if I run it as `python django-admin.py`, then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                         
  File "django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                              
    from django.core import management                                                                                     
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the following helped to start working with localization -

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5"

brew install gettext
brew link gettext --force

mkdir conf
mkdir conf/locale
python /usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/bin/django-admin.py makemessages -l ru
```

(btw, [here is](http://blog.yjl.im/2009/02/using-django-i18n-in-google-app-engine.html) good, but old article about django translation usage with GAE; see also [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#django))